# Comparing different implementations with random seeds

Tags: c++, boost, random-seed

I have two implementations of a program, one using lists and one using vectors, in order to compare their runtimes. The class functions in each implementation are different, since the list implementation allows more flexibility in code. They both also use random number generators.

I set both to have random seed 0 and ran them, but the results I get are not the same.

One question I have is, if both implementations call a function using a random seed, e.g.

```
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::exponential_distribution<>> random_n(seed, boost::exponential_distribution<>()) ;
```

and one calls it *more* times than the other implementation, will that cause desynchronization with respect to random seeds?

To be more specific, the vector implementation simulates a [Poisson Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) on a continuous real segment, e.g. [0,1], whereas the list implementation simulates the PP on separate partitions: {[0,0.1], [0.1,0.2], [0.2,0.3], ..., [0.9, 1]} and then combines the results. Simulating a PP on the big partition could mean as few as 1 boost::exponential_distribution calls, but simulating on the 10 partitions requires at least 10 boost::exponential_distribution calls, even if none of them may be used (e.g. if they overshoot the partition).

Even though probabilistically, these methods should generate the same kind of results, would the seeds between the programs be de-synchronized? And if so, is there any way to resynchronize them without changing the implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with de-synchronized? However, a seed only means that you have the same pseudo-random numbers in several runs. If both methods do some different operations on this pseudo-random numbers, then (obviously) you get different results.

Comment: A pseudo-random number generator produces a sequence of numbers from an initial seed and guarantees, for the same generator implementation, the same sequence is always generated for each seed. I understand that by desynchronization, you mean each program generated different number of elements of the same sequence. So, you can sync them again generating and discarding the rest of elements in the program that is behind or simply reset both generators to some known seed again. But how could a resync after they produced the result would help you?

Comment: My main motivation is that I want to compare the run-time of both implementations on essentially the same set of random inputs, otherwise one implementation may be dealing with a much harder problem instance than the other, for example. Also, it would be nice if they both returned the same answers to verify that they are running correctly. But in a case like this where the random samples are generated differently, would you say that's impossible?

Comment: You have to handle the RNG number as the same input in both implementations... ie. you can't throw it away just because it's outside of current partition, then you should probably switch partition or somehow buffer then number to get into result later. Or you may generate fixed input data, which are pre-sorted per partitions, so they can be used by both implementations. But if real world usage allows non-sorted data, which have to be filtered, then it's sort of cheating, making it easier for the list variant.

Comment: Okay thanks, that clears up my initial question of whether throwing out RNGs is causing the problem. I think buffering the result may indeed be the way to go here. Now I am much more aware of the preciousness of RNGs :P

Comment: Going back to your aim - performance testing - why not accept that they're working with random numbers, and just go with an average?  Run your application a (large) number of times, pick different seeds each time and then compare the average speeds.  It wouldn't mean very much testing with 1 seed anyway, because what if it was faster just for that seed.